# difference between "set JAVA_HOME" and "setlocal" in catalina.bat for tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat8

I want to set the JAVA_HOME variable in my tomcat (tocat/bin/catalina.bat) to point to my JDK installed in my system so that the servlet engine will be able to work with Java.

Actually I need to add the following in the batch file for that:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

but my question is there are already a `setlocal` exist in that batch file without being configured as below:

```
setlocal
```

when I start the tomcat without set the JAVA_HOME variable in the batch file it just started and the page can be loaded successfully in my web browser.

Can I know the function of this line in the batch file ? Do I need to replace this `setlocal` line with the `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45` or just leave as it is and add one new line. Will it be affect my development later on?

Answer (score 1):

Use **setlocal** to change environment variables when you run a batch file. Environment changes made after you run **setlocal** are local to the batch file. **Cmd.exe** restores previous settings when it either encounters an **endlocal** command or reaches the end of the batch file. (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx))

1. > when i start the tomcat without set the JAVA_HOME variable in the batch file it just started and the page can be loaded succesfully in my web browser.

   It probably works because you have your JAVA_HOME environment variable set (you can check it by doing one of these:

   - Start -> Run -> "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables -> Ok -> Check System Variables
   - Start -> Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Check System Variables
   - Start -> cmd.exe -> echo %JAVA_HOME%
2. > Can i know the function of this line in the batch file ? Do i need to replace this "setlocal" line with the "set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" or just leave as it is and add one new line. Will it be affect my development later on?

   You can use **set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45** because if you pay attention to catalina.bat you'll see at some point the following line:
   `if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal`
   Changes made to an Environment Variable after SETLOCAL has been issued are local to the batch file.
3. > Can i know the function of this line in the batch file ? Do i need to replace this "setlocal" line with the "set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" or just leave as it is and add one new line. Will it be affect my development later on?

   If you have multiple JDKs installed on your system, you add the line **set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45** in you **catalina.bat** file